# Create a NSManagedObject and inject into a SwiftUI view which is automatically added to the navigation stack

Tags: core-data, swiftui

My main app screen displays a list of objects (Patients in this instance). I want to allow the user to add a new patient by tapping a toolbar button which allows them to add the relevant details.

Implementing an edit view was easy enough and editing existing patients works without issue. It is also easy enough to add a new patient in the list view without any automatic modal display of, or navigation to, the edit view. The downside of course is that the user will need to manually go through an additional sequence of steps to edit the newly added object which isn't very user friendly.

It's not a problem if I use MVVM but I'm trying to do it using Apple's own "recommended" approach with property wrappers around the MOC, etc. As I can't access the MOC until initialisation of the view is complete, the simplest approach (creating a new Patient if the view isn't provided with one) isn't possible. The current tactic (creating the new object in the parent view) leads to state inconsistency and some very weird behaviour with the NavigationLink being triggered whenever you try to edit the fields in the child.

I'm sure I'm making this unnecessarily complex and am still stuck in an imperative mindset but some guidance would be helpful.

```
struct PatientsView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var dataController: DataController
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
    static let tag = "patients"
    
    @State private var navLinkTag: Int? = 0
    
    let patients: FetchRequest<Patient>
    
    init() {
        patients = FetchRequest(entity: Patient.entity(), sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Patient.creationDate, ascending: false)])
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(patients.wrappedValue) { patient in
                    PatientRow(patient: patient)
                }
                .onDelete { offsets in
                    for offset in offsets {
                        let item = patients.wrappedValue[offset]
                        dataController.delete(item)
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Patients")
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem {
                    Button(action: {
                        navLinkTag = 1
                    }, label: {
                            Image(systemName: "plus")
                    })
                    .background(
                        NavigationLink(
                            destination: EditPatientView(patient: newPatient()),
                            tag: 1,
                            selection: $navLinkTag,
                            label: { EmptyView() })
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func newPatient() -> Patient {
        let patient = Patient(context: managedObjectContext)
        patient.creationDate = Date()
        patient.name = "New patient"
        
        dataController.save()
        
        return patient
    }
}

struct PatientRow: View {
    @ObservedObject var patient: Patient
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            NavigationLink(destination: PatientActivityView(patient: patient)) {
                VStack {
                    HStack {
                        Text(patient.patientName)
                        Text(patient.patientOwnerName)
                            .bold()
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    
                    HStack {
                        Text(patient.patientSpecies)
                        Text(patient.patientSex)
                        Text(patient.age)
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    .font(.caption)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct EditPatientView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var dataController: DataController
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
    
    @State var owner: String
    @State var name: String
    @State var species: String
    @State var dob: Date
    @State var sex: String
    
    let patient: Patient
    
    init(patient: Patient) {
        self.patient = patient
        
        _owner = State(wrappedValue: self.patient.patientOwnerName)
        _name = State(wrappedValue: self.patient.patientName)
        _species = State(wrappedValue: self.patient.patientSpecies)
        _sex = State(wrappedValue: self.patient.patientSex)
        _dob = State(wrappedValue: self.patient.patientDateOfBirth)
    }
    
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Section(header: Text("Identity")) {
                TextField("Name", text: $name.onChange(update))
                TextField("Owner", text: $owner.onChange(update))
            }
            
            Section(header: Text("Signalment")) {
                TextField("Species", text: $species.onChange(update))
                TextField("Sex", text: $sex.onChange(update))
                DatePicker("Date of birth",
                           selection: $dob.onChange(update),
                           in: ...Date(),
                           displayedComponents: .date)
                    .datePickerStyle(CompactDatePickerStyle())                }
        }
        .navigationTitle("Edit Patient")
    }
    
    
    private func update() {
        patient.name = name
        patient.owner = owner
        patient.species = species
        patient.sex = sex
        patient.dateOfBirth = dob
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, think I've got it. It seems a little hacky but I'm having to dance around the SwiftUI lifecycle. Adding a new Patient instance to the persistent store will invalidate PatientsView causing a refresh of the hierachy and this was the source of my problems before.

I have to say, the time I've spent on this bending my head around the issue has been an interesting exercise but does make me think that data / business logic should definitely be kept completely separate from the view layer when using SwiftUI. MVVM and/or Redux-like architectures would avoid this issue entirely.

All the changes were made within PatientsView so I've been able to leave PatientEditView untouched - on balance I'm reasonably happy but am very open to suggestions on how this could be improved.

```
import SwiftUI

struct PatientsView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var dataController: DataController
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
    
    @State private var showEditPatient = false
    @State private var newPatient: Patient? = nil /// need to use @State as the PatientView FetchedResult will change when Patient is added or mutated causing the hierachy to be discarded and refreshed. A "normal" property will be re-created leading to multiple new Patient instances and warnings about state amendment during a view update
    
    private let patients: FetchRequest<Patient>
    
    init() {
        patients = FetchRequest(entity: Patient.entity(), sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Patient.creationDate, ascending: false)])
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        let createNewPatient = Binding<Bool>( /// A custom binding seems to be the best way of creating new Patient instances only when required
            get: { return showEditPatient },
            set: { newValue in
                if !newValue {
                    newPatient = nil /// EditPatient view has been dismissed so discard the Patient
                } else {
                    if newPatient == nil { newPatient = createPatient() } /// New Patient required 
                }
                showEditPatient = newValue
            }
        )
        
        return NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(patients.wrappedValue) { patient in
                    PatientRow(patient: patient)
                }
                .onDelete { offsets in
                    for offset in offsets {
                        let item = patients.wrappedValue[offset]
                        dataController.delete(item)
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Patients")
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem {
                    Button(action: {
                        createNewPatient.wrappedValue = true
                    }, label: {
                        Image(systemName: "plus")
                    })
                }
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $showEditPatient,
                   onDismiss: { createNewPatient.wrappedValue = false }) {
                EditPatientView(patient: newPatient!) /// Patient should never be nil - force unwrap will catch unexpected code path
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func createPatient() -> Patient {
        let patient = Patient(context: managedObjectContext)
        patient.creationDate = Date()
        patient.name = "New patient"
        
        dataController.save()
        
        return patient
    }
}

struct PatientsView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static let dataController = DataController.preview
    
    static var previews: some View {
        PatientsView()
            .environment(\.managedObjectContext, dataController.container.viewContext)
            .environmentObject(dataController)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is new managed objects and edited ones are handled differently. I would have separate views:

```
struct EditPatientView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var dataController: DataController
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
    
    @State private var owner: String
    @State private var name: String
    @State private var species: String
    @State private var dob: Date
    @State private var sex: String
    
    let patient: Patient
    
    init(patient: Patient) {
        self.patient = patient
        
        _owner = State(wrappedValue: self.patient.patientOwnerName)
        _name = State(wrappedValue: self.patient.patientName)
        _species = State(wrappedValue: self.patient.patientSpecies)
        _sex = State(wrappedValue: self.patient.patientSex)
        _dob = State(wrappedValue: self.patient.patientDateOfBirth)
    }
    
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Section(header: Text("Identity")) {
                TextField("Name", text: $name.onChange(update))
                TextField("Owner", text: $owner.onChange(update))
            }
            
            Section(header: Text("Signalment")) {
                TextField("Species", text: $species.onChange(update))
                TextField("Sex", text: $sex.onChange(update))
                DatePicker("Date of birth",
                           selection: $dob.onChange(update),
                           in: ...Date(),
                           displayedComponents: .date)
                    .datePickerStyle(CompactDatePickerStyle())                }
        }
        .navigationTitle("Edit Patient")
    }
    
    
    private func update() {
        patient.setValue(self.name, forKey: "patientName")
        patient.setValue(self.owner, forKey: "patientOwnerName")
        patient.setValue(self.species, forKey: "patientSpecies")
        patient.setValue(self.sex, forKey: "patientSex")
        patient.setValue(self.dob, forKey: "patientDateOfBirth")
        
        do {
            try self.managedObjectContext.save()
        } catch {
            //Handle any error
        }
    }
}
```

and for new patients:

```
struct NewPatientView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var dataController: DataController
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
    
    @State private var owner: String = ""
    @State private var name: String = ""
    @State private var species: String = ""
    @State private var dob: Date = Date()
    @State private var sex: String = ""
        
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Section(header: Text("Identity")) {
                TextField("Name", text: $name)
                TextField("Owner", text: $owner)
            }
            
            Section(header: Text("Signalment")) {
                TextField("Species", text: $species)
                TextField("Sex", text: $sex)
                DatePicker("Date of birth",
                           selection: $dob,
                           in: ...Date(),
                           displayedComponents: .date)
                    .datePickerStyle(CompactDatePickerStyle())
            }
            Button(action: {
                self.save()
            }) {
                Text("Save")
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("New Patient")
    }
    
    
    private func save() {

        let patient = Patient(context: self.managedObjectContext)
        patient.name = name
        patient.owner = owner
        patient.species = species
        patient.sex = sex
        patient.dateOfBirth = dob

        do {
            try self.managedObjectContext.save()
        } catch {
            //Handle any error
        }
    }
}
```

I would also consider making Owner it's own Entity that is linked to each animal through a Relationship. Otherwise, you are constantly duplicating owners if they have more than one animal. I know I do.

Also, while I kept your same pattern of updating the managed object for every entry, you may want to consider waiting to update until the user taps a save button. That way the user has a chance to clear the edits and start over.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I should have defined my question a little better - I was trying to avoid code duplication and was wanting to re-use the editing view if at all possible as this is the way I would have approached the problem using UIKit. Any ideas? With regards to the data structure, I completely agree - I'm in the first iteration of the project("quick and dirty"!) and am focusing on patient-related functionality. I will be sorting the relationships out properly once the core of the app is working.

Comment: The only other thought I had was to send the managed object in as an optional. You could test for that and decide whether you want to edit or make a new one. However, you may want to specialize these views such that you would find it easier to make the views separate, rather than one big complex view. SwiftUI really encourages lots of simple views, and you could save on coding by reusing common subviews. There is little or no cost to doing that. For onboarding a new patient, you may want to ask a series of questions, rather than just fill out a form. That really comes from a user perspective.